# Validation for the phone number using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mask

I have a form which gets the phone number from the user.And it stores in the pattern (xxx)xxx-xxxx. For pattern generation I'm using angular mask. The problem I face here is in the validation. If the input field is blank, it gives an alert message for the first time after adding a number, if again the input field is blank, there is no alert message it getting added to the list.

Controller

```
$scope.addphone = function () {
    //added = false;
    if ($scope.phone== '' || $scope.phone == undefined || $scope.phone== null) {
     alert ("Enter Invalid number or Check the Number entered");
      return '';
    }

    //checkig for already existing number
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.phonelist.length; j++) {
      if (angular.equals($scope.phonelist[j], $scope.phone)) {
        added = true;
      }
    }
    if (!added) {
      $scope.phonelist.push($scope.phone);
      $scope.phone = {};
    } else {
      alert('Number Already Exist');
    }
  }
```

html:

```
<form name="valdate">
            <div style="width:180px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; border:1px solid #000;">
              <input type="tel" name="phoneno" minlength="13" maxlength=13 ng-model="phone.number" mask="(999)999-9999" />
           <span ng-show="valdate.phoneno.$error.required">phone</span>
            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: same code is working after replacing ng-model="phone.number" with ng-model="phone"

Comment: issue is resolved. `$scope.phone= ' '`.